# Django & Djoser 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, django, djoser

I keep having an error whenever I try to PATCH in order to update a specific user info.
As per Djoser documentation, the endpoint is located in **/users/me/**

https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html#user

Everything is working fine except this part.
I have a Custom User model and overrided the default (again, as per documentation)
**'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer'**,

serializer.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        read_only_fields = ('password'),
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active')
```

models.py

```
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Un email est obligatoire')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

What am I missing?

Edit with Traceback error

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: PATCH Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/me/
>
> Django Version: 4.0 Python Version: 3.10.1 Installed Applications:
> ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> 'rest_framework',  'rest_framework.authtoken',  'corsheaders',
> 'djoser',  'companies',  'accounts'] Installed Middleware:
> ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
> 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
> line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py",
> line 125, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\djoser\views.py",
> line 175, in me
> return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py",
> line 82, in partial_update
> return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py",
> line 67, in update
> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py",
> line 227, in is_valid
> self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py",
> line 429, in run_validation
> value = self.validate(value)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\djoser\serializers.py",
> line 54, in validate
> validate_password(password, user)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 47, in validate_password
> validator.validate(password, user)   File "C:\Users\minse\Desktop\Code
> snippets\Project\FluchtV0.4\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\password_validation.py", line 145, in validate
> if SequenceMatcher(a=password.lower(), b=value_part.lower()).quick_ratio() >= self.max_similarity:
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/users/me/ Exception Value:
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Can you add the full traceback from the error to your question

Comment: Just edted my post. Hope this helps

Comment: I think you need to include the field `password` as a `read_only` field in the serializer.

Comment: I have edited and tested by adding password as a read_only field. Still not working :(

Comment: Do you get a new error or is it the same one?

Comment: I got the same error.
Just made another test by deactivating the current_user and get back to the djoser default: PATCH request is ok but no update is done
body:
{
    "last_name": "dsf"
}
Authorization header passed with JWT token...

I'm losing my mind ....

Comment: I do not know djoser, but it seems that it is trying to compare the password with the user's name (username, or some other analogous field), to validate that they are not too similar, and one of the fields is not defined. Try to find out what the other field is (if the password is defined), and maybe from there you will get something clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got the same error while override Djoser's UserCreateSerializer

This solution works fine for me

```
class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True)

class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
```